# Passing type in Scala as an argument

Tags: java, json, scala, generics, reflection

I want to pass a type to a function in Scala.

*Problem in detail*

**First iteration**

I have the following Java classes (coming from an external source):

```
public class MyComplexType {
    public String name;
    public int number;
}
```

and

```
public class MyGeneric<T> {
    public String myName;
    public T myValue;
}
```

In this example I want `MyComplexType` to be the the actual type of `MyGeneric`; in the real problem there are several possibilities.

I want to deserialize a JSON string using a Scala code as follows:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

object GenericExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val jsonString = "{\"myName\":\"myNumber\",\"myValue\":{\"name\":\"fifteen\",\"number\":\"15\"}}"
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val myGeneric: MyGeneric[MyComplexType] = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[MyGeneric[MyComplexType]])
    val myComplexType: MyComplexType = myGeneric.myValue
  }
}
```

it compiles fine but runtime error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyComplexType
        at GenericExample$.main(GenericExample.scala:9)
```

**Second iteration**

Working solution to the problem:

```
val jsonString = "{\"myName\":\"myNumber\",\"myValue\":{\"name\":\"fifteen\",\"number\":\"15\"}}"
val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
val myGeneric: MyGeneric[MyComplexType] = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[MyGeneric[MyComplexType]]) 
myGeneric.myValue = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.readTree(jsonString).get("myValue").toString, classOf[MyComplexType])
val myComplexType: MyComplexType = myGeneric.myValue
```

Not nice but works. (If anybody knows how to make it better, that would also welcome.)

**Third iteration**

The lines in the solution of second iteration occur in the real problem several times, therefore I want to create a function. The altering variables are the JSON formatted string and the `MyComplexType`.

*I want something like this:*

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val jsonString = "{\"myName\":\"myNumber\",\"myValue\":{\"name\":\"fifteen\",\"number\":\"15\"}}"
  val myGeneric = extractMyGeneric[MyComplexType](jsonString)
  val myComplexType: MyComplexType = myGeneric.myValue
}

private def extractMyGeneric[T](jsonString: String) = {
  val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  val myGeneric = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[MyGeneric[T]])    
  myGeneric.myValue = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.readTree(jsonString).get("myValue").toString, classOf[T])
  myGeneric
}
```

This does not work (compiler error). I've already played around with various combinations of `Class`, `ClassTag`, `classOf` but none of them helped. There were compiler and runtime errors as well. Do you know how to pass and how to use such a type in Scala? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `jackson` to parse json, you can use [TypeReference](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to parse `generic` type. Example:

```
val jsonString = "{\"myName\":\"myNumber\",\"myValue\":{\"name\":\"fifteen\",\"number\":\"15\"}}"
val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
val reference = new TypeReference[MyGeneric[MyComplexType]]() {}
val value: MyGeneric[MyComplexType] = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, reference)
```

if you still want to use `Jackson`, I think you can create a parameter with `TypeReference` type. like:

```
  implicit val typeReference = new TypeReference[MyGeneric[MyComplexType]] {}
  val value = foo(jsonString)
  println(value.myValue.name)


  def foo[T](jsonStr: String)(implicit typeReference: TypeReference[MyGeneric[T]]): MyGeneric[T] = {
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, typeReference)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! To extend it: the `TypeReference`should be imported as follows: `import org.codehaus.jackson.\`type\`.TypeReference`.

Comment: This is a nice solution for "first iteration" problem, thank you! However, it does not solve the problem raised in the "third iteration", i.e. the main problem. That is still open; indeed there are a few more other things to do, therefore it would be nice to create a separate function. The most straightforward solution (passing `MyGeneric[MyComplexType]` as generic type) results in runtime error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyGeneric`.

Comment: @CsabaFaragó you can check my update, hope it can help you.

Comment: "if you still want to use `Jackson`" - indeed, what else can I use?

Comment: Nice list, thank you! Jackson seemed to be the most common approach in Scala. Which one is currently the most preferred main stream solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using your approach, I think this is how you can get classes that you need using `ClassTag`s:

```
def extractMyGeneric[A : ClassTag](jsonString: String)(implicit generic: ClassTag[MyGeneric[A]]): MyGeneric[A] = {
  val classOfA = implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]
  val classOfMyGenericOfA = generic.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[MyGeneric[A]]]
  val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  val myGeneric = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classOfMyGenericOfA)
  myGeneric.myValue = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.readTree(jsonString).get("myValue").toString, classOfA)
  myGeneric
}
```

I am not familiar with jackson but in play-json you could easily define `Reads` for your generic class like this

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit def genReads[A: Reads]: Reads[MyGeneric[A]] = (
  (__ \ "myName").read[String] and
  (__ \ "myValue").read[A]
)((name, value) => {
    val e = new MyGeneric[A]
    e.myName = name
    e.myValue = value
    e
})
```

Having this, and provided that instance of `Reads` for `MyComplexType` exists, you can implement your method as

```
def extractMyGeneric[A: Reads](jsonString: String): MyGeneric[A] = {
  Json.parse(jsonString).as[MyGeneric[A]]
}
```

the issue here is that you need to provide `Reads` for all of your complex types, which would be as easy as

```
implicit complexReads: Reads[MyComplexType] = Json.reads[MyComplexType]
```

if those were case classes, otherways I think you would have to define them manually in simillar way to what I've done with `genReads`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Meanwhile the other thread solved my problem, along with a Jackson improvement as well. I save your solution for possible further type related problems.